# Is it acceptable to use two plurals side by side?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> However, high data volume and multiple data sets with poor linkages continued to frustrate their efforts to identify key **issues drivers**.

Is it acceptable to use two plurals side by side?

Comment: That doesn't sound very idiomatic. Could you please provide more info about what you are trying to convey? Your sentence could be like: _However, high data volume and multiple data sets with poor linkages continued to frustrate their efforts to identify key issue drivers._ But I did not understand the meaning in the context.

Comment: In some types of writing (business, technical), you can get away with it, as long as you put a slash between the two terms ("issues/drivers"). In most cases, though, you're better off choosing one term or the other, or combining them with "and".

Comment: I wonder whether the intended meaning could be "drivers of key issues". If so, that would be the better way to put it.

Comment: What @JackO'Flaherty said. But putting that aside, the ***syntactic principle*** involved here is that we normally use the singular form for attributive nouns - aka ***noun adjuncts*** (not ***nouns adjuncts***, even though they would switch to plural if I rephrased to refer to them as ***adjuncts of nouns***).